# RxJava. Where are the operators?

Tags: java, rx-java, observable

I am looking at these documentation pages:

http://reactivex.io/documentation/single.html
http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/start.html

talking respectively about the RxJava single object and  start operator, but I cannot figure out how to find them. The observable class does not have a static "start" method, and no way to create a "single" object. 
I imported both the rxjava and rxjava-async packages though maven.

Thank you.

Comment: Please refine this post to be 1 question, or split it into 2 questions on stack overflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Single` is marked as `@Experimental` in the [latest source](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/blob/1.x/src/main/java/rx/Single.java), and has not made it to the [current maven release](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Cio.reactivex%7Crxjava%7C1.0.12%7C) (1.0.12, updated 2015.06.09). From reading the docs, it appears that you would use a `Single` instead of an `Observer`. I understand that the documentation follows the latest source, rather than the latest current release.

`Start` is available as a method of `rx.util.async.Async` in the [0.21.0 maven release](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Cio.reactivex%7Crxjava-async-util%7C0.21.0%7Cjar). You need an `Async` instance instead of an `Observer` to call it on; see variants of `Async.toAsync()` for details.

Comment: Maybe Start has been removed because I am using version 1.0.12 and there is no start in neither rxjava-async or rxjava-async-utils.

Comment: Is there a way for me to use something marked as @Experimenal?

Comment: According to their docs, `@Experimental` features are subject to change at any time - it is better to not rely on them. That being said, `Single` is available in the latest 1.0.13 snapshots: https://oss.jfrog.org/webapp/search/artifact/?0&q=rxjava